# How to fix failed to lazily initialize a collection

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

When i try to get data from db about user, i get the following error:

```
Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed
    to lazily initialize a collection of role: com.hramyko.finalapp.entity.CommonUser.comments, could not initialize
    proxy - no Session
```

I know that happened bcs my session is closed, but i don't want to use eager fetch. What methods are there to solve my problem? I read the solution to my problem on stackoverflow, but it does not help me.

My CommonUser class:

```
package com.hramyko.finalapp.entity;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "common_users")
public class CommonUser extends User {

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "author")
private List<Comment> comments;

public CommonUser() {
}

public CommonUser(User user) {
    super(user.getEmail(), user.getPassword(), user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName(),
            user.getCreatedAt(), user.getRole(), user.getStatus());
    this.id = user.getId();
}

public CommonUser(String email, String password, String firstName,
              String lastName, Date createdAt, Role role, Status status, List<Comment> comments) {
    super(email, password, firstName, lastName, createdAt, role, status);
    this.comments = comments;
}

public List<Comment> getComments() {
    return comments;
}

public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
    this.comments = comments;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    if (!super.equals(o)) return false;
    CommonUser that = (CommonUser) o;
    return Objects.equals(comments, that.comments);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(super.hashCode(), comments);
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "CommonUser{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", email='" + email + '\'' +
            ", firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
            ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
            ", comments=" + comments +
            ", createdAt=" + createdAt +
            ", role=" + role +
            '}';
}
```

}

Service:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public User currentUser() {
    Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    String username;
    if (principal instanceof UserDetails) {
        username = ((UserDetails) principal).getUsername();
    } else {
        username = principal.toString();
    }
    return userRepository.findUserByEmail(username);
}

@Transactional
@Override
public User findUserByEmail(String email) {
    userValidator.validateEmail(email);
    return userRepository.findUserByEmail(email);
}
```

Controller:

```
@PreAuthorize("hasAnyAuthority('user.read', 'user.write', 'user.delete')")
@GetMapping("my_account")
public String show() {
    return userService.currentUser().toString();
}
```

Comment: Does the exception occurs because of the .toString() in the controller?

Comment: @pL4Gu33 yup. I transferred to the service and everything worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because you are accessing comments in User 's `toString()` but the comments are not initialised yet and the transaction that load the user is already closed .

Typically two ways to solve it :

1. Use [fetch join](https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-difference-join-left-join-fetch-join/#JOIN_FETCH) to also fetch the comments when loading this user
2. Increase the transaction boundary to cover the controller 's show() method such that when you access `user.toString()` in it , the transaction that load the user is still active and not closed yet :

```java
@Transactional
public String show() {
    return userService.currentUser().toString();
}
```